# Spring boot Multipart file upload along with json data

Tags: database, angular, spring-boot

I want to write api using Spring boot Multipart file upload as part of json body and also want to save img url in database.
Requests that look like this:

```
------WebKitFormBoundarynBsAcX7rJhOGsmfY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fdata"; filename="blob"
Content-Type: application/json

{"firstname":"saurabh","lastname":"mishra","mobile":"943847557"}
------WebKitFormBoundarynBsAcX7rJhOGsmfY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files"; filename="download.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundarynBsAcX7rJhOGsmfY--
```

Please help me to find the solution.

Comment: 1) Format your code using the {} formatter while posting.  2) Include your own attempts for solving the issue and where you are getting struck

Answer (score 1):

I solve this issue in this way.

> My API Method

```
@RequestMapping(value="/filestore/{bucket-uuid}/appsport.com/singleFileUploadWithObject/{folder}",
        method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String singleFileUploadWithObject(
        @PathVariable(name="bucket-uuid", required = true) String bucketUUId,
        @PathVariable(name="folder", required = false) String folder,
        FileWithObject rawData) {
    return pingResponse;
}
```

> My FileWithObject DTO

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "file", "files", "data" })
public class FileWithObject<T> {

    @JsonProperty("file")
    private MultipartFile file;
    @JsonProperty("files")
    private MultipartFile[] files;
    @JsonRawValue
    @JsonProperty("data")
    private T data;
    // getter/setter and other...
}
```

> Note:- For data parameter you can use the mapping process in the singleFileUploadWithObject method
> hope it's help you and other

[image]